# Schemas or different databases - SQL Server 2008?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design

We are developing a system that contains multiple platforms (e.g. video, forum etc).

As a database platform we are using SQL server 2008.

I have one question from database aspect.

Is it better to have one centralize database for all platforms separated on different schemas or have different databases for every platform?

Note: Platforms need to communicate (via services). All users need to have Single Sign Point and share all personal information across platforms.

Also, consider database maintenance and partitioning.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not enough information. Can you explain why you think you need separate schemas OR separate databases? Can you put some kind of metrics on "fast data growing"? That's kind of like "big" - to some people, 100 GB is big, to others it is absolutely tiny.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Firstly, forget about fast data growing, it's confusing... My main point is do I need to go with different schemas (schema for every platform, but one centralize database) or different databases (separate databases for every platform). If we go with schemas (1 database) probably the database will be very large (in amount of tables) but I have all data in one place. If we go with separate databases for every platform does it will be hard to maintain? What will happen with some relational data (like users share same info, authentication, on all platforms)?

Comment: [This](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/) would probably clear your doubts. Hope it helps.

Comment: The part: 'Advantages of using schemas', clear my doubts. Thank you. I will mark as answer but I want to listen other suggestions too.

Comment: No problem :) The joy of getting to know that I was of help to someone is far bigger than getting my reply marked as the answer. Cheers !!

Comment: It is always the easiest way to have one database only. Why *wouldn't* you do that?

Comment: How you conclude that is always easiest way to have one database only?